# grub-mkconfig adding entry for other Linux system but ignoring its Grub config

Tags: dual-boot, grub, grub2-mkconfig

I've got a machine with two Linux systems and Windows. When I run `grub-mkconfig` from my Ubuntu Mate system, it identifies and creates entries for itself, the second Linux system (KISS Linux), and Windows.

Mystifyingly, when I look at `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` on the Ubuntu system, the entry for KISS Linux isn't there! However, it still appears on the Grub menu.

Furthermore, I've set up some custom kernel parameters in the `/etc/default/grub` file on the KISS Linux system, but they don't propagate to the Grub config file.

What have I misunderstood or messed up?

Comment: What Linux's do you have - you mention a "Ubuntu Mate system", but you don't say what the other one is. Could you edit your question with this info?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are looking at the grub that is default boot?

And a major update of the other system will change it to default boot. I believe os-prober is just searching for other installs & not using settings from other system.

If you want those settings use a configfile type entry to load the other system's grub.cfg. See 6.5 on configfile details:

https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Multi_002dboot-manual-config

Use labels and configfile to boot another install

https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive/344359#344359

https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Multi_002dboot-manual-config

https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Multi_002dboot-manual-config

I turn off os-prober and only add entries I want into 40_custom:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332570/how-do-i-stop-grub-from-scanning-particular-disks/1332664#1332664